# Не выводятся данные из mysql-запроса в div с помощью ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте.
Помогите, пожалуйста. Из select берётся значение, передаётся в insert.php, где происходит запрос к базе. При success в  должны передаваться обработанные в файле php данные. Но в диве ничего не выводит, даже есть я в php-файле просто echo "текст"; напишу.
Вот ajax-запрос:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select_dep_edit").onchange(function (){
        var name_dep = $("#select_dep_edit").val();
        $.ajax({
            url : 'insert.php', 
            data : 'name_dep=' + name_dep, 
            type : POST, 
            success : function (data){ 
                $("#edit_login").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй проследить что отдает insert.php, может к нему путь не правильно прописан. На примере хрома: открой консоль (F12),  затем перейди на вкладку Network и кликнись на фильтр XHR. Затем попробуй отправить аякс запрос и посмотри что отдаст файл insert.php на вкладке Network. Также перейди в консоль, убедить что там нету ошибок.

Updated:
1) правильно $("#select_dep_edit").change(function () 
тоесть не onchange, а просто change
2) правильно type : 'POST', а не  type : POST

Comment: с onchange консоль мне выдала ошибку, я её решила, а вот что не так с POST было, понять не могла. Спасибо вам большое.